# SPARQL query to return all concepts related to Afghanistan from DBPedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

How to write `SPARQL` query to return all concepts related to Afghanistan from `DBpedia`?

SPARQL is new for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "concepts"? The classes shown (http://dbpedia.org/page/Afghanistan)[here] in the `rdf:type` section?

Comment: concept mean All information related to Afghanistan. i need a SPARQL query to get all related things to Afghanistan from DBPedia.

Comment: To be honest, you should start with a SPARQL tutorial then. I mean, this is quite a simple query. for outgoing information, i.e. information about Afganistan, use: `SELECT * {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Afghanistan ?p ?o }` For incoming, reverse the triple. For both, use `UNION`

Comment: thank you, actually i do not know sparql, but this is part of my assignment, i tried to learn but to be honest it is not easy for beginners.

Comment: What kind of assignment is it? What is the overall task? SPARQL isn't that difficult. RDF is made of triples resulting in some kind of graph, SPARQL tries to matches those triple resp. parts of the graph, thus, queries contain triple patterns

Comment: documentation for Afghanistan archive project in linked data subject. is there any good tutorial to learn RDF and SPARQL from start.

Answer (score 1):

The following query made to [DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/) results in showing complete data related to Afghanistan as a resource which could either be subject or object.

```
PREFIX dbr:<http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

SELECT ?subject ?predicate ?object

WHERE {

{dbr:Afghanistan ?predicate ?object.} UNION 
{?subject ?predicate dbr:Afghanistan.}


}
```

P.S. [Learning SPARQL](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920020547.do) book might be interesting!

[image: Learning SPARQL]